# Eigen Matrix cannot be passed by reference: lvalue reference to tvalue error

Tags: c++, eigen

my class `Batman` has the following function:

```
void doFoo(Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> &results){
  ...
}
```

And I am trying to call the function like this:

```
const int dim=3
Eigen::Matrix<int, dim, 1> results;
indices.resize(dim,1);

Batman bat();
bat.doFoo(results);
```

But I am getting the following Error:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>’

Why?? The types should be the same? And what is the right way to do it?

****EDIT****
Thanks to the comment I found out that the const int was the problem here, using int works.

Before that I looked a little bit into openSource Software and noticed that most use some templates like this:

```
        template <typename WrongMatrixType>
    static NearestNeighbourSearch* createKDTreeLinearHeap(const WrongMatrixType& cloud, const Index dim = std::numeric_limits<Index>::max(), const unsigned creationOptionFlags = 0, const Parameters& additionalParameters = Parameters())
```

Comment: Maybe, try `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, 0, 3> results;` or just `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> results`. After having looked into the [doc.](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) I got the impression that `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>` and `Eigen::Matrix<int, dim, 1>` might result into two different types, which results in an implicit type cast in `bat.doFoo(results);` which in turn is not valid for a reference. Though, in fact, the error message looks a bit strange... ;-)

Comment: `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>` and `Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 1>` are two different types. Compiler is allowed to make one implicit conversion. In your case it creates temporary instance of `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>` from `Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 1>` and tries to pass this temporary into `results`, but temporary cannot be bound to non-const Lvalue reference. As solution, results may take Matrix by const reference. Also this `Batman bat();` is function declaration, not creation of object.

Comment: yeah I had the same idea but that is super strange. Do you know what the right way is? it seems like I have to use some type of template

Comment: Are you sure it is `int dim = 3;` but not `const int dim = 3;`?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. It is indeef const int. I had to change it because if I use only int I get 'Non-type template argument is not a constant expression' Without const int it works! Thanks alot @Scheff'sCat .

Comment: Did you get a solution to this @Emilio7773? If so, can you please post it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Joe yes for my case it helped to delete the const before the dimension declaration. But looking into open source software most people use templates, I would not feel confident enough to post it as an answer, I added it as an EDIT to my question

Comment: Ok thanks @Emilio7773, I appreciate your response! I found another similar question but still not many great solutions to this.

Comment: You cannot pass a `Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 1>` as `Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> &` -- even though they are convertible, but the target must be an rvalue-reference, a const-reference or a value. It is not clear for me, if you already solved your issue -- please post a [mre] of your original question and open new questions if they are different from your original problem.